# How to get my google account from which i created a google plus app

Tags: google-plus

i created a google plus application but i forgot from which account did i create it..

i have the details

```
'google_application_name'  => 'Foodtech', 
  'google_client_id'        => 'XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  'google_client_secret'    => 'XXXXX',
  'google_redirect_uri'     =>  base_url().'googleplus_connect/login',
  'google_developer_key'    => 'XXXXX',
  'google_email_id'         => 'XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
```

how can i get the account??

Answer (score 1):

There is no lookup service for a client ID.  However, you can see all of the projects for an account by visiting the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).  For a full list of projects that account owns, click on the drop down menu in the upper left, and choose `Open` under the `Other projects` listing.  By visiting this site for each Google account that you own, you should be able to find your project.